# How to compute an accuracy measure based on RMSE? Is my large dataset normally distributed?

Tags: normal-distribution, large-data

I have several datasets on the order of thousands of points.  The values in each dataset are X,Y,Z referring to a coordinate in space.  The Z-value represents a difference in elevation at coordinate pair (x,y).

Typically in my field of GIS, elevation error is referenced in RMSE by subtracting the ground-truth point to a measure point (LiDAR data point).  Usually a minimum of 20 ground-truthing check points are used.  Using this RMSE value, according to NDEP (National Digital Elevation Guidelines) and FEMA guidelines, a measure of accuracy can be computed: Accuracy = 1.96*RMSE.

This Accuracy is stated as: "The fundamental vertical accuracy is the value by which vertical accuracy can be equitably assessed and compared among datasets.  Fundamental accuracy is calculated at the 95-percent confidence level as a function of vertical RMSE."

I understand that 95% of the area under a normal distribution curve lies within 1.96*std.deviation, however that does not relate to RMSE.

Generally I am asking this question:  Using RMSE computed from 2-datasets, how can I relate RMSE to some sort of accuracy (i.e. 95-percent of my data points are within +/- X cm)?  Also, how can I determine if my dataset is normally distributed using a test that works well with such a large dataset?  What is "good enough" for a normal distribution?  Should p<0.05 for all tests, or should it match the shape of a normal distribution?

---

I found some very good information on this topic in the following paper:

http://paulzandbergen.com/PUBLICATIONS_files/Zandbergen_TGIS_2008.pdf

Comment: Watch out!  Your use of ks.test is incorrect.  According to the [help page](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/ks.test.html), you need to use 'pnorm' instead of 'dnorm'.  Moreover, setting the comparison distribution's parameters to the mean and SD of the sample itself will substantially inflate the p-value: "If a single-sample test is used, the parameters specified in ... must be pre-specified and not estimated from the data."

Comment: The reference to "cartographic applications" is intriguing.  May I suggest that you explain more about your application and exactly *why* you think you need a normally distributed dataset?  A huge number of questions on this site attest to a common misunderstanding of what is really required when people think data should be "normal".

Comment: Added some context to my question.  For some reason I cannot get the link to your for "help page" to work.

Comment: Well, actually, that formula will not give you a confidence interval: it will be far too large for that.  It really is a crude (but standard) way to estimate a *tolerance interval,* which is the middle 95% of the whole population of differences.  There are good reasons to suppose the differences will *not* have a normal distribution: larger absolute differences tend to be associated with larger topographic slopes.  Assuming your 4000 points are a random sample of those differences, why don't you just report their 2.5 and 97.5 percentiles?

Comment: (I fixed the link to the help page.  You can get to it with the R command `?ks.test`, too.)

Comment: The 4000 points, for example, is my entire dataset, not a random sample.  From NDEP (National Digital Elevation Guidelines Program) guidlines:  "The fundamental vertical accuracy (FVA) is the valu eby which vertical accuracy can be equitably assessed and compared among datasets.  Fundamental accuracy is calculated at the 95-percent confidence level as a function of vertical RMSE."
Does this help?

Comment: Meant to add, this is referring to the Accuracy=1.96*RMSE equation

Comment: Your data form a *statistical sample* of the elevations that could be measured. When you talk about "accuracy" you are making claims about how closely your DEMs represent the *entire population* of elevations. In your case, it is impossible to assess accuracy by comparing datasets: you have to "field-truth" your data. Thus, the guidelines are really talking about *relative agreement* of two datasets. Finally, their use of "confidence level" is mistaken, as I explained earlier. I accept you have to work within the framework of awful guidance like this, but you deserve to know what's correct.

Comment: Thanks for your time!  I do understand the guidelines are in the realm of ground-truthing the data.  My research is building upon this topic in some ways.  I am assessing the difference from a witheld set of test points to the DEM to test how DEM grid size and interpolation methods effect the accuracy of the DEM.
Is there another way that I can relate RMSE to some sort of accuracy (i.e. 95-percent of my data points are within +/- X cm)?

Comment: That's starting to sound like a useful question for you.  Because you haven't yet received any answers, why don't you just completely edit the current question to incorporate the information you have disclosed in these comments?  I would suggest broadening it somewhat: after quoting the guidelines (to show what kind of methods are usually employed in your field), you might ask quite generally how to use the distribution of the *ordered pairs of differences in elevations* to assess accuracy (assuming one of the data sets is the reference).

Comment: All: Updated my main post and question to reflect the changes from the comments.

Answer (score 1):

> Using RMSE computed from 2-datasets, how can I relate RMSE to some sort of accuracy (i.e. 95-percent of my data points are within +/- X cm)?

Take a look at a near duplicate question: [Confidence interval of RMSE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78079/confidence-interval-of-rmse)?

> Is my large dataset normally distributed?

A good start would be to observe the empirical distribution of `z` values. Here is a reproducible example.

```r
set.seed(1)
z <- rnorm(2000,2,3)
z.difference <- data.frame(z=z)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(z.difference,aes(x=z)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=1,aes(y=..density..), fill="white", color="black") +
  ylab("Density") + xlab("Elevation differences (meters)") +
  theme_bw() + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

At a first glance, it looks normal, right? (actually, we know it is normal because the `rnorm` command we used).

If one wants to analyse small samples over the dataset there is the Shapiro-Wilk Normality Test.

```
z_sample <- sample(z.difference$z,40,replace=T)
shapiro.test(z_sample) #high p-value indicates the data is normal (null hypothesis)

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  z_sample
W = 0.98618, p-value = 0.8984 #normal
```

One can also repeat the SW test many times over different small samples, and then, look at the distribution of `p-values`.

Be aware that normality tests on large datasets are not so useful as it is explained in this [answer](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-April/129620.html) provided by Greg Snow.

> On the other hand, with really large datasets the central limit theorem comes into play and for common analyses (regression, t-tests, ...) you really don't care if the population is normally distributed or not.
>
> The good rule of thumb is to do a qq-plot and ask, is this normal enough?

So, let's make a QQ-plot:

```
#qq-plot (quantiles from empirical distribution - quantiles from theoretical distribution)
mean_z <- mean(z.difference$z)
sd_z <- sd(z.difference$z)
set.seed(77)
normal <- rnorm(length(z.difference$z), mean = mean_z, sd = sd_z)

qqplot(normal, z.difference$z, xlab="Theoretical", ylab="Empirical")
```

[image]

If dots are aligned in the `y=x` line it means the empirical distribution matches the theoretical distribution, which in this case is the normal distribution.