# RMSE vs Standard deviation in population

Tags: standard-deviation, rms

RMSE (Root mean square error) and SD (Standard deviation) have similar formulas.

[This link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78079/confidence-interval-of-rmse) says

> The only difference is that you divide by  $n$ and not  $n−1$ since
>   you are not subtracting the sample mean here. The RMSE would then
>   correspond to  $\sigma$ . Therefore, the population RMSE is  $\sigma$
>   and you want a CI for that.

So I want to know whether RMSE and SD are the same. Also, I want reference about it.

Answer (score 19):

*TLDR;* While the formulas may be similar, RMSE and standard deviation have different usage.

You are right that both standard deviation and RMSE are similar because they are square roots of squared differences between some values. Nonetheless, they are not the same. Standard deviation is used to measure the *spread* of data around the mean, while RMSE is used to measure *distance* between some values and prediction for those values. RMSE is generally used to measure the error of prediction, i.e. how much the predictions you made differ from the predicted data. If you use mean as your prediction for all the cases, then RMSE and SD will be exactly the same.

As a sidenote, you may notice that mean is a value that minimizes the squared distance to all the values in the sample. This is the reason why we use standard deviation along with it -- they are related species!

Comment: @Chill2Macht it is not about spread vs distance, but about spread of single variable vs distance between predicted and true values.

Comment: That does make a lot of sense actually. If we considered the distance between the predicted and true values to be a variable itself, would it be appropriate in your opinion to say that the RMSE is also a measure of the spread of that variable? "Spread of the distance"?

Comment: @Chill2Macht but then you *will* be calculating standard deviation.

Comment: @Chill2Macht RMSE is not sd of errors. Sd(errors) = mean((errors - mean(errors))^2) while rmse = mean(errors^2)

Comment: That hits the nail on the head -- thank you for your time.

Comment: Worth noting that as the mean error approaches 0 and n approaches infinity sd and rmse converge.

Comment: @Tim I think you're missing the square root. It should be Sd(errors) = square root( mean((errors - mean(errors))^2))

Comment: Hey Tim! Just wondering whether it would be simpler to say that what the standard deviation is to the mean, is the root mean square error to the regression line?

Answer (score 4):

This will make bit clear,
**RMSE** calculated between two sets, eg: set and predicted set, to calculate the error,
eg :

```
price Vs predicted price 
10         12
12         10
13         17
```

$$ {RMSE}=\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N{(F_i - O_i)^2}}{N}} $$
f = forecasts (expected values or unknown results),
o = observed values (known results).

we find the difference of each row, then sum the differences, and square it, divided by N and finally root...
(or you can use a single fixed predicted value and subtract from all rows)

**RMSD** will use a single set to calculate the spread, (not between predicted, but itself)

```
price 
10         
12         
13
```

$$ {RMSD}=\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N{(x_i - \mu_i)^2}}{N}} $$
μ is the average value

Comment: This answer would be improved if you used math typsetting. More information: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: "_find the difference of each row, then sum the differences, and square it_"  Not quite, you're summing the squared differences.

Answer (score 0):

We're in the middle of the Australian Open as I write this, so forgive me if I am stretching analogies.

Suppose we're playing tennis, and our random variable is where the opponent's ball will cross the baseline (the back line of the court).

Some opponents will play it safe. They always hit near the middle of the court. In that case, the *Standard Deviation* is low. Other opponents will constantly aim for the sidelines. Assuming they go for both the forehand and backhand sidelines, the *Standard Deviation* will be higher. SD is a property of the population.

The better we are at predicting where any given shot will cross the baseline, the lower our *Root Mean Squared Error*. RMSE is a property of our estimates. If our forecasts are correct (and we have enough athletic ability), then our RMSE can be much lower than the SD, hopefully close to zero. If we always guess the wrong direction (we're unlikely to play in the Open in that case), our RMSE can be much higher than the SD.